# Set interface to API's response in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, axios

I'm using typescript and React for developing web page.

Do I declare all response's `interface` when calling APIs?

Here is my React code.

```js
// Do I have to do this all times ?
interface DataObj {
  bred_for: string;
  breed_group: string;
  height: { [key: string]: string };
  id: number;
  life_span: string;
  name: string;
  origin: string;
  temperament: string;
  weight: { [key: string]: string };
}

const Main: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<DataObj[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBreeds = async () => {
      const data: AxiosResponse = await apis.getBreeds();
      setData(data.data);
    };
    fetchBreeds();
  }, []);
  return (
  ...
```

I don't want to write whole response's `key`. Help me !!

Comment: Yes, otherwise how would you define of what type a prop should be? And it's not that bad, at a glance someone could know what kind of props they are supposed to pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I always wonder that this way is right.

Comment: Just a tip, you can pass `DataObj` to your AxiosResponse to tell it what you expect to get: `AxiosResponse<DataObj>`

Comment: Awesome !! It makes clear what I want. Thanks !!